# async Task<object> function deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

```
    public async Task<UserInfo> GetUserDataAsync(string NetworkID)
    {
        PrincipalContext principalcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADDomain, ADUser, ADPass);
        UserPrincipal founduser = null;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            founduser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalcontext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, NetworkID);
        });

        //task.Wait();

        return founduser != null && founduser.Enabled == true ?
            new UserInfo
            {
                DisplayName = founduser.DisplayName,
                Email = founduser.EmailAddress,
                NetworkID = founduser.SamAccountName
            } : new UserInfo();
    }
```

This is a function that suppose to verify a user through ad, I am able to run the function with Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {}); and task.Wait(); but that would still run the function synchronously. Running the code above with async and await puts the browser in a deadlock which spins forever and never returns a value.

Comment: Why bother getting the UserPrincipal in a task anyway?

Comment: @Ananke, what would you suggest using?

Comment: I think i am going to remove the async and await from this function and just use the task.factory.startnew functionality to execute this operation. Unless anyone else have any other idea?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is why not just call it synchronously? UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity is not inherently asynchronous.

Comment: @Ananke, Yes I just used the synchronous function with Task.
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                founduser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalcontext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, NetworkID);
            });

            task.Wait();

Comment: @SamHaider but what we are asking is why use a task at all. All you are doing is adding overhead. just do `founduser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalcontext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, NetworkID);` and drop the tasks completely.

Comment: He's not just adding overhead if `FindByIdentity` ends up communicating with a remote Active Directory server.  I/O operations like that are exactly the kind of thing you want to perform asynchronously.

Comment: Async should be ok to do.  I'm just wondering where is the code when the browser is looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this asynchronously, why not just return the task directly?

```
public Task<UserInfo> GetUserDataAsync(string NetworkID)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        PrincipalContext principalcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADDomain, ADUser, ADPass);
        UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalcontext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, NetworkID);


        return founduser != null && founduser.Enabled == true ?
          new UserInfo
          {
            DisplayName = founduser.DisplayName,
            Email = founduser.EmailAddress,
            NetworkID = founduser.SamAccountName
          } : new UserInfo();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am just going to add async and await before the Task.Run and that would do it...

Answer (score -1):

This is what I end up doing with my synchronous call.

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                founduser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalcontext,IdentityType.SamAccountName, NetworkID);
            });

            task.Wait();
```

Comment: You're still (needlessly) using the Task imho. Just write `founduser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(...)` instead of the five lines above.

Comment: He knows the above version is silly.  He's wondering why the version in his question (which uses `await`) seems to never complete, while the blocking version above completes successfully, despite the fact that both use a `Task` to call `FindByIdentity`.